# winjs toolbar change alignment of buttons and menu

Tags: winjs

is it possible to change the allignment of the buttons and "..."-menu in a winjs-toolbar from right (Default) to left?

I would like to have all Buttons and the menu on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

ok I found the solution :)
just for everyone who has the same needs: 
add the

```
style="direction:rtl" to the toolbar.
```

Default: ltr (left to right)
rtl (right to left)
...

```
<div class="basicToolbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToolBar" style="direction: rtl">
```